# Override default WordPress core translation

Tags: translation, language

WordPress is set to Dutch language. When I use `get_the_archive_title()` my theme correctly outputs "Categorie: Category-name" on a category archive page. However I'd like that to read "Sectie: Category-name".

I do not want to change the Dutch language file in the wp-content/languages folder, because that will be updated by WordPress updates.

I tried copying that translation file, altering the "category" translation and putting the new nl_NL.mo file into my-theme/languages. This did not have any effect.

How can I achieve a different translation for some strings without altering the core translation files?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use [gettext filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext):

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'cyb_filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
function cyb_filter_gettext( $translated, $original, $domain ) {

    // Use the text string exactly as it is in the translation file
    if ( $translated == "Categorie: %s" ) {
        $translated = "Sectie: %s";
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

If you need to filter a translation with context, use [`gettext_with_context` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext_with_context):

```
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'cyb_filter_gettext_with_context', 10, 4 );
function cyb_filter_gettext_with_context( $translated, $original, $context, $domain ) {

    // Use the text string exactly as it is in the translation file
    if ( $translated == "Categorie: %s" ) {
        $translated = "Sectie: %s";
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

A translation with context means that a context is given in the gettext function used to translate the string. For example, this is without context:

```
$translated = __( 'Search', 'textdomain' );
```

And this is with context:

```
$translated = _x( 'Search', 'form placeholder', 'textdomain' );
```

Similar filters are available for plural translations (`[_n()][2]` and `[_nx()][2]`): [`ngettext`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/ngettext/) and [`ngettext_with_context`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/ngettext_with_context/).

Comment: That worked! I had to do "Categorie: %s" and "Sectie: %s" because the text has to be exactly as in the translation file.

Comment: Oh, yes, that is correct. I didn't know the exact text to translate.

Comment: Great piece of code – just be aware that the `gettext` filter won’t catch translations that use a "context" string, those will need [gettext_with_context](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext_with_context).

Comment: Thanks for this great solution. As I am building a child theme and willing to override some of the parent theme's translations, I substituted the proposed function body with the following line `return $domain != 'child-domain' && ( $new = __( $original, 'child-domain' ) ) != $original ? $new : $translated;`.
In this way, I can housekeep the overriding translations in the child theme's PO file instead of having them cabled in the function code.

Comment: Thanks cybmeta! I used this technique to change core text with a plugin I published in the repo. I credited this post in the code. https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-admin-email-setting-without-outbound-email/

Answer (score 4):

I was about to use the "add_filter( 'gettext'..." solution suggested above but then read at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/ that this solution can have quite a negative performance impact. I suggest to therefore go with alternative solutions where possible.
In my case I can copy a theme template file to my child theme and edit the string in the template file. This can be a great solution but it of course doesn't help for strings that don't appear in template files.

PS: I meant to add this as a comment but unfortunately I'm not allowed to do so yet.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to use `get_the_archive_title` filter in your *functions.php*:

```
function archive_title_modify( $title ) {
    return str_replace('Categorie: ', 'Sectie: ', $title);
}
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', 'archive_title_modify');
```

The advantage is that it's called only once per page, instead on every translated string as with `gettext` filter.