# Prevent wordpress from updating language files

Tags: updates, language

I would like to prevent wordpress from updating language files in languages folder. Not only in case of automatic updates, but also in case of manual ones. I have tried few solutions including change file permissions, but was not able to succesfully solve this when manually updating core files, so any help regarding this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to override translations, you should [use gettext filter](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188332/override-default-wordpress-core-translation) instead of modifiying language files.