# How to customize password reset message page on success if no error in password reset

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, hooks

I tried `login_message` filter with `$_GET['action'] && resetpass` but I want it on success password message page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the "Your password has been reset." message.

You say you've tried the [login_message filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_message/) and that should work, so your problem is likely that your code isn't getting loaded. Put your filter code in a [mu-plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/plugins/mu-plugins/) not a regular plugin to ensure it gets loaded for the login page. Rather than testing for the action I'd test if the message contains `__( 'Your password has been reset.' )` instead.

Here's the code from wp-login.php:

```php
login_header(
    __( 'Password Reset' ),
    wp_get_admin_notice(
        __( 'Your password has been reset.' ) . ' <a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Log in' ) . '</a>',
        array(
            'type'               => 'info',
            'additional_classes' => array( 'message', 'reset-pass' ),
        )
    )
);
```

As you can see there's nothing obvious to filter there. You could also

1. Use a gettext filter to catch exact matches for "Your password has been reset." and replace it with your own string, e.g. [see this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188339/3276). I don't particularly like this, but you're already having to check for a text match ‍♀️ so maybe it's not too bad.
2. Filter [wp_admin_notice_markup](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_admin_notice_markup/) instead. Here you could check for the reset case using the additional_classes argument containing reset-pass, but you're going to have to make a string substitution into the message mark-up too, so this isn't very nice either.

So there aren't any particularly good options here, sorry.